# How do I process an yaml array in puppet ERB template?

Tags: yaml, puppet, erb, hiera

I have some hiera data that looks like this:

```
netapp_nfs_shares:
  - 10.199.1.34:/os_cloud
  - 127.0.0.2:/example
```

This gets passed to my class as parameter and gets used in a erb template file that looks like this:

```
# This file was generated from nfs-shares.conf.erb by puppet
<% Array(@netapp_nfs_shares).each do |line| -%>
<%= line %>
<% end -%>
```

But when I puppet agent runs I get a file that looks like this:

```
# This file was generated from nfs-shares.conf.erb by puppet
["10.199.1.34:/os_cloud", "127.0.0.2:/example"]
```

I was hoping that I would get a file that looks like this:

```
# This file was generated from nfs-shares.conf.erb by puppet
10.199.1.34:/os_cloud
127.0.0.2:/example
```

I suspect that the template I wrote has something wrong with it. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You have a *YAML* array only in your Hiera data file.  You don't need to do anything special to transform it into a *Puppet* array -- that happens automatically when Hiera retrieves it, whether during automatic data binding (your case) or when you use the `hiera()` function to retrieve it manually.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this should do it:

```
<% @netapp_nfs_shares.each do |line| -%>
<%= line %>
<% end -%>
```

I suspect that by using Array() you are wrapping your array in another.